# Interface is not being called android

Tags: java, android, interface

I have used a interface to determine weather the async task is finish or not.But when i use the interface,the 2 methods of that interface is not being called.

The Custom Adapter Class

```
public class MyResourceCustomAdaper extends BaseAdapter {


    static GetMatchingJobsArray getMatchingJobsArray;


    public MyResourceCustomAdaper(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;


    }

    public static void setInterface(GetMatchingJobsArray getMatchingJobsArray) {
        MyResourceCustomAdaper.getMatchingJobsArray = getMatchingJobsArray;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        doing stuffs here


        return view;
    }
}



public static class GetMatchingJobsAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String response;
    Context c;


    public GetMatchingJobsAsync(Context c) {

        this.c = c;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {


        calling web method here

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        arrayMatchingJobs = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();



                getMatchingJobsArray.getMatchingJobs(true, arrayMatchingJobs);// here i am passing my array to the interface


                getMatchingJobsArray.hasCompleted(true);

                Intent i = new Intent(c, MyResourceMatchingJobs.class);
                c.startActivity(i);




        }
    }


}

public interface GetMatchingJobsArray {

    public void getMatchingJobs(boolean value, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayMatchingJobs);

    public void hasCompleted(boolean value);

}

}
```

Class where i am implementing the interface

```
public class MyResourceMatchingJobs extends Activity implements MyResourceCustomAdaper.GetMatchingJobsArray {
    private ListView listView;
    private MyResourceMatchingJobsCustomList adapter;
    private static ProgressDialog pDialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_resource_matching_jobs_list);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_my_resource_matching_jobs);
        MyResourceCustomAdaper.setInterface(this);//use for initailizing the interface



    }


    @Override
    public void getMatchingJobs(boolean value, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayMatchingJobs) {

adapter = new MyResourceMatchingJobsCustomList(MyResourceMatchingJobs.this, arrayMatchingJobs);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void hasCompleted(boolean value) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Here in this activity why my interface is not being called???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here in this activity why my interface is not being called???

Because Calling `getMatchingJobs`  when  `MyResourceMatchingJobs` Activity is not running.

So try to call both methods after starting `MyResourceMatchingJobs` Activity from `onPostExecute`.

Suggestion: becuase sending `arrayMatchingJobs` and one boolean value so use `i.putExtra(KEY,VALUE)` for getting both values in `MyResourceMatchingJobs` Activity

Comment: @Anuj: Why starting `MyResourceMatchingJobs` Activity from `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: Then how will i call the new activity?